# SQL Server 2012 create assembly failed - invalid attribute

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sqlclr

I'm trying to integrate a DLL into my SQL Server 2012 database, following the example from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524(v=sql.105).aspx).

The command is:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY Excel_Procs_IF 
FROM 'd:\MyDir\UWQ_Excel_Compute.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE ;
```

and I get the following error message:

> Msg 6215, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because method 'get__Default' on type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range' in safe assembly 'UWQ_Excel_Compute' has invalid attribute 0x1083.

I have no idea what this means nor how to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `PERMISSION_SET` in your `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement to be `UNSAFE`. Then it should work.

As stated on the MSDN documentation page for [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx):

> To use the features of a Microsoft Office application from an Office project, you must use the primary interop assembly (PIA) for the application. The PIA enables managed code to interact with a Microsoft Office application's COM-based object model.

And, the page for [Primary Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch(v=vs.100).aspx) states:

> A primary interop assembly is a unique, vendor-supplied assembly that contains type definitions (as metadata) of types implemented with COM.

COM is unmanaged code, and that requires the `UNSAFE` Permission Set.